# Can websites collect browser data without using http requests?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, browser-extensions, fingerprinting

Is it possible for a website to collect data such as the plugins/fonts installed without sending it thought http requests?

If so, is there any plugin for any browser that tells the user what type of information the website is trying to extract from the browser?

Comment: Perhaps your question is *when* does a browser send data like installed fonts to a server?

Comment: Like HTTPS, WebRTC, Web Sockets, etc?